# How to paginate a table in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, pagination

I have a table which i want to paginate. I tried many solutions given on forum but they keep giving me some or other error. I want to show 3 records per page.I tried to include bootstrap but it also throws error for me.
I used this plnker http://plnkr.co/edit/79yrgwiwvan3bAG5SnKx?p=preview but html5 doesnt support  element. It throws null reference error at js.minify code block

```
//HTML for the view


<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover  table-striped" at-config="config">
    <thead>
       <tr style="white-space: nowrap;">
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Organization No</th>
          <th>Contract No</th>
          <th>Company Name</th>
          <th>Plan No</th>
          <th>Status</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="mas in vm">
       <td>{{mas.startDate | amDateFormat:&#39;YYYY-MM-DD&#39;}} </td>
        <td>{{mas.organizationNumber}}</td>
        <td>{{mas.contractNumber}} </td>
        <td>{{mas.name}}  </td>
        <td>{{mas.planNumber}} </td>
        <td>{{mas.description}} </td>
        <td><span><a href="#" ng-click="getErrorDetailBySearch(mas.productAccountOid,mas.planNumber,mas.migrationRunID)">Details</a></span></td>
    </tr>                
</table>
```

> controller code:

```
// it binds the data to vm
var onSuccess = function (response) {
    $scope.vm = response;
    if ($scope.vm < 1) {
        messageService.noDataFound();
     }
}
// it binds the dat
```

Comment: The link you provided works fine. Your table markup doesn't contain any buttons and your controller is missing things (surely that's not all). Provide more information and someone may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

The plunker you referenced are using `ui-bootstrap`, which is a set of bootstrap components written in pure angularjs. That way, you don't need jQuery in your project.

In *ui-bootstrap* there is a `<pagination>` directive. A component that handles the pagination for you. You need to input some variables to that control, to create the pagination control; like *total items* and *items per page*.

How to use the [pagination directive is documented here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination). Remember when you include it in your project, add it as a dependency.

```
angular.module('your-app', ['ui.bootstrap');
```